# Missing Dynamic method

Tags: groovy

I´m trying to add a dynamic method in the Integer class

```
static {
    Integer.metaClass.daysInFuture {
        System.currentTimeMillis() + (60000 * 60 * 24 * delegate)
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it

```
1.daysInFuture
```

I´m receiving

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: daysInFuture for class: java.lang.Integer
```

What I´m doing wrong?

EDIT:

I create this Unit Test

```
public class GroovyTest {

    static {
        Integer.metaClass.double {
            2 * delegate
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        assert 1.double == 2
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your static block? Where are you calling it from? Can you come up with a simple example that we can run that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I create a unit test, take a look